# Redefine already defined UI-Router state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Let's say the state was already defined with:

```
$stateProvider.state('stateName', { ... });
```

How can it be redefined or modified (e.g. in another config block)?

Comment: No, it can't be done. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: you could look at `$urlRouterProvider.deferInterceptor()`

Comment: @latata I still hope it is doable but tricky. The example is redefining default state and user-defined states in the app where I don't have full control over code base.

Comment: @PankajParkar Any hints on how it would be helpful?

Comment: @estus we have dynamic search criteria that vary by user. Right now, when a user logs in, the state for the search is already defined, we'd love to re-define the state w/ the new search criteria for that user (after the state has already been defined).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently had the same problem. I wanted to manipulate existing states in a separate js-file. Ended up with something like this.

```
angular
   .module('app')
   .run(['$state', MyNewRouting]);

function MyNewRouting($state) {
    var state = $state.get('home');
    state.redirectTo = 'MyNewState';
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot about the question, I think it can be the accepted answer. I figured it out some time ago the same way. To avoid race conditions in 'run' it can be also done within $state decorator.

Comment: Good Solution. Worked fine for me